# Contador de clicks con ajax y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Quisiera saber si tienen un ejemplo de como hacer un conteo de `click` en una etiqueta `<a></a>` Y que ese `click` se guarde en una base de datos para que así después se cuente el total de veces cliqueado.
En la red encuentras pero con formularios y lo que quiero hacer es sin formulario, sólo una que en un etiqueta se vaya a java o ajax y que lo mande a **PHP** sin que me recargue la pagina.

Comment: Deberías, al menos, compartir algo que has hecho para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, puedes usar **jquery** con el método **.on**  capturas el evento a partir de un **id** que le coloques a la etiqueta y después lo enviar al servidor **$.post**. Así siempre que te hagan clic en la etiqueta  te va a enviar el dato el servidor por **post**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con el método [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de jQuery. Por ejemplo:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ejemplo</h1>
    <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
// una vez que termine de cargar el dom
$(document).ready(function() {
  // selector del link
  var a = $('#stackoverflow');

  // evento click del link
  // también se puede usar a.click(function(e) {})
  a.on('click', function(e) {
    // esto es sólo un ejemplo de cómo pasar parámetros
    var id_row = 1;

    // método ajax para contar el click
    $.ajax({
      url: 'contador.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {id: id_row},
      // en caso de éxito de la petición
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

#### contador.php

```
<?php

// obtengo el id del $_POST
$id = $_POST["id"];

// acá debería estar la conexión a la DB
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

// incremento en la db el contador
$query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE contadores SET click=click + 1 WHERE id = $id");

$msg = array('msg' => 'error');
if ($query === TRUE) {
  $msg['msg'] = 'success');
}

// esto es importante, la información que devuelve tiene que ser siempre un json
echo json_encode($msg);

// cierro la conexión
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: en el <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a> tendria que llevar un id? como lo tienes en la funcion var a = $('#stackoverflow');
ejemplo
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" id ="stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a>

Comment: En realidad cualquier cosa, es para seleccionar con jQuery el elemento del dom. Funciona como el selector de CSS.